# specifying <!doctype> and <html> attribute

Tags: html, doctype

When starting an html document I always write

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
```

But there are lots of sites writing it as

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Is there a danger in doing it the way I do ? Whats the benefit of all the extra attributes?

Comment: The lower one is for XHTML, your's is for HTML5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those sites are using before html5 version.But you are using html5 version.In html5 you can simply specify the doctype like

```
<!doctype html>
```

But in previous versions(before html5) we have doctype like

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the HTML5 doctype, see http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/ and http://alistapart.com/article/doctype/

Answer (score 0):

What you're setting your doctype to is HTML5. The other versions you've seen are for the lower (HTML4.01, etc) versions.

As far as I am aware, using the HTML 5 tag should cause too many problems unless people are viewing your site on older (IE6 or lower) browsers.

You can find a more comprehensive guide here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Answer (score 0):

Usually a `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration is used to distinguish between versions of HTMLish lanaguages (in this case, HTML or XHTML).

Different markup languages will behave differently. For example is height:100%

> NOTE:(This is important): Do not mix HTML with XHTML

You'll notice that the height of the components is drastically different, and the only difference between the documents!!!!